# Cannot read image file in oracle 11g forms, getting error frm-47100

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm unable to read the image from the file location. But If I do re-save via `MS-Paint` the same image then I'm able to load successfully. I want to load image directly instead of re-save.  Error getting like `frm-47100 Cannot read image file`.

Following thing I hava done with help of webutil:

```
vfilename := client_get_file_name('c:\', file_filter => ' Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.gif)|*.gif|(*.png)|*.png|');
client_image.read_image_file(vfilename,'jpg','image_blob');
```

Urgnet Help really appreciated.

Comment: Try this: client_image.read_image_file (vfilename, SUBSTR(vfilename, INSTR(vfilename, '.', -1) + 1), 'block_name.item_name' ); If it fails too, try 'JPEG' istead 'JPG' in client_image.read_image_file.